# How to get the SparkSession to find added python files

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, bigdl

After running `pip install BigDL==0.8.0`, running `from bigdl.util.common import *` from python completed without issue.

However, with either of the following SparkSessions:

```
spark = (SparkSession.builder.master('yarn')
    .appName('test')
    .config("spark.jars", "/BigDL/spark/dl/target/bigdl-0.8.0-jar-with-dependencies-and-spark.jar")
    .config('spark.submit.pyFiles', '/BigDL/pyspark/bigdl/util.zip')
    .getOrCreate()
)
```

or

```
spark = (SparkSession.builder.master('local')
    .appName('test')
    .config("spark.jars", "/BigDL/spark/dl/target/bigdl-0.8.0-jar-with-dependencies-and-spark.jar")
    .config('spark.submit.pyFiles', '/BigDL/pyspark/bigdl/util.zip')
    .getOrCreate()
)
```

I get the following error.

```
ImportError: ('No module named bigdl.util.common', <function subimport at 0x7fd442a36aa0>, ('bigdl.util.common',))
```

In addition of the `'spark.submit.pyFiles'` config above, after the SparkSession successfully starts, I have tried `spark.sparkContext.addPyFile("util.zip")`  where "util.zip" contains all of the python files in https://github.com/intel-analytics/BigDL/tree/master/pyspark/bigdl/util .

I have also zipped all of the contents in this folder https://github.com/intel-analytics/BigDL/tree/master/pyspark/bigdl (branch-0.8) and pointed to that file in the `.config('spark.submit.pyFiles', '/path/to/bigdl.zip')`, but this also does not work.

How do I get the SparkSession to see these files?

Answer (score 3):

Figured it out.  The only thing that worked was `spark.sparkContext.addPyFile("bigdl.zip")` after the SparkSesssion has started.  Where "bigdl.zip" contained all of the files in  https://github.com/intel-analytics/BigDL/tree/master/pyspark/bigdl (branch-0.8).

Not sure why `.config('spark.submit.pyFiles', 'bigdl.zip')` would not work.